# WPF event bubbling and tunneling

Tags: wpf, events, event-bubbling

I have the following 3 nested elements:

When I handle the event...

> `e.Handled = true;` in any of the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`
>   methods.  The `KeyUp` event is not fired at all.

When I comment-out `e.Handled = true;` everything works fine.

Are the events `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` and `KeyUp` dependent somehow?

I thought only tunneling/bubbling paired events (for example **PreviewKeyDown** and **KeyDown**) were dependent on one another.

```
<DockPanel Name="Level1" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Level1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
           KeyUp="Level1_KeyUp">
 <Grid Name="Level2" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Level2_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"                                                                                                                      
           KeyUp="Level2_KeyUp">
   <Button Height="25" 
           Width="120"
           Name="Level3" 
           Content="Button"
           Click="Level3_Click"                 
           PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Level3_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"  
           KeyUp="Level3_KeyUp"/ >       
 </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Here are the event implementations:

```
private void Level1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Level1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown");
}

private void Level2_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Level2_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown");
        //e.Handled = true;
}

private void Level3_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Level3_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown");
}

private void Level3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Level3_Click");
}

private void Level3_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Level3_KeyUp");
}

private void Level2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Level2_KeyUp");
}

private void Level1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Level1_KeyUp");
}
```

Why is not happening the same way in the following different example?

```
<StackPanel PreviewKeyDown="StackPanel_PreviewKeyDown" KeyUp="StackPanel_KeyUp">
        <Grid Height="100" PreviewKeyDown="Grid_PreviewKeyDown" KeyUp="Grid_KeyUp">
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Width="100" Height="50" Margin="201,134,216,-84" PreviewKeyDown="button_PreviewKeyDown" KeyUp="button_KeyUp"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Events implementations:

```
    private void StackPanel_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("StackPanel_PreviewKeyDown " + e.GetHashCode());
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Grid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Grid_PreviewKeyDown " + e.GetHashCode());
    }

    private void button_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("button_PreviewKeyDown " + e.GetHashCode());
    }

    private void StackPanel_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("StackPanel_KeyUp " + e.GetHashCode());
    }

    private void Grid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Grid_KeyUp " + e.GetHashCode());
    }

    private void button_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("button_KeyUp " + e.GetHashCode());
    }

    private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Window_PreviewKeyDown " + e.GetHashCode());
    }

    private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Window_KeyUp " + e.GetHashCode());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The RoutedEventArgs is shared between tunneling and bubbling events, so when you handle your tunneling event bubbling is never executed.

More reading on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747183(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: In the following example, marking as e.Handled in a PreviewKeyDown event handler does not supress the execution of the KeyDown ev. handler. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events

Comment: Because the Key evt is managed below in the visual tree of the composed component.